# Chef server won't start

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, chef-infra

Trying to get chef-server to start I get the following error:

```
[root@SCM: /etc/chef]$ /etc/init.d/chef-server-webui start
 * Starting chef-server-webui                                                                          
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:14: uninitialized constant Gem::UserInteraction (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:4
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/provider/package/rubygems.rb:31
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/providers.rb:59
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef.rb:25
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/sbin/chef-server-webui:42
```

And here is my gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.0.18)
bunny (0.7.6)
chef (0.10.4)
chef-server-webui (0.10.4)
coderay (1.0.0)
daemons (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
extlib (0.9.15)
haml (3.1.3)
highline (1.6.2)
json (1.5.2, 1.4.6)
merb-assets (1.1.3)
merb-core (1.1.3)
merb-haml (1.1.3)
merb-helpers (1.1.3)
merb-param-protection (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.16)
mixlib-authentication (1.1.4)
mixlib-cli (1.2.2)
mixlib-config (1.1.2)
mixlib-log (1.3.0)
moneta (0.6.0)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.1)
ohai (0.6.4)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.3.3)
rake (0.9.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
systemu (2.4.0)
thin (1.2.11)
treetop (1.4.10)
uuidtools (2.1.2)
yajl-ruby (1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Chef bugtracker issue](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2138) for exactly this problem. Short summary: Chef seems to pick up different versions of RubyGems from different places after it was upgraded.

Rewinding the upgrade to RubyGems seems to help.

Comment: Thanks.  I too found that issue just yesterday.  I backed out to rubygems 1.3.? and then upgraded to the one chef was happy with.